# Weird storyboard push segue when updating app to iOS 7.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, storyboard

Currently I am updating my app for iOS 7. When I build and run the app it works but the layout needs some serious tweaking, that is not the problem.

When I navigate to another view in the application the screen gets pushed for about 50% and disappears then. The attached image describes the problem:

[image]

The application uses a `storyboard`, and the `storyboard` segue is just a simple "push" segue within a navigation controller.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is what a push segue looks like under iOS7. The incoming view controller actually floats in over the top of the previous one, which only moves a small distance out of the way. Look at the transitions in the settings app, for example, and you will see what I mean.

The problem you have is that the incoming view appears to have a clear background colour, so you can still see the content underneath. I think the default background colour for some views has changed for iOS 7 as well - try setting a background colour and you should see a much better transition.

Comment: I believe there is a flag to drop back to iOS 6 style segues too. Will see if I can find it.

Comment: If there isn't (i haven't found one yet..), you can implement custom transition animations using iOS 7's transitioning APIs

Comment: Awesome, Thanks, this worked :-) Didn't notice the new transition style yet.

Answer (score 1):

Using the animation transition mechanism in iOS 7 you can specify the transition in both directions.

Set the segue to Push, then see code below which implements the old style iOS 6 push transition:

https://github.com/Dzamir/OldStyleNavigationControllerAnimatedTransition